# Is there a good overview to find connector types?

Tags: connector

While taking a look into my overheating B&O speakers, I unfortunately ripped off a connector. Now I need an exact matching replacement, but I did not find it in any online-shop by filtering.

So my more general question is: **Do you know a good website/database to find out the type of a connector?**

If there is none, can you help me to find the type of the connector in the image below? There are 2x10 rectangular pins with a rough 1mm pitch.

[image: picture of broken connector]

Edited: It is an DF50-20DP-1V by Hirose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you don't care about every connector that might have existed, but only those you can actually buy, the kind-of-logical-ain't-it answer to your first question (list?) is:

Go to one of the large electronic distributor's websites, click through to the connector listings, and select filters that describe your connector.

Regarding your second question (ID this connector?): a 24-contact mezzanine rectangular connector, photographed very much out of focus ;) (more pixels don't help if they aren't sharp; try photographing at a larger distance next time). I'd do exactly the same: I'd have to go to a distributor website, click through to the rectangular connectors, and peruse the filters until I found few enough potential matches. You can do the same, AND you have the connector (or its remnants) at hand, so you stand a better chance than I do to find the right connector.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. I looked at conrad and mouser before, but was overwhelmed by the filters, as I do not know most of the terms. So what is the best approach in your opinion? Measuring the pitch (also select surrounding values), the size of the connector (including pins for the PCB?). And whats the best store to filter in your opinion? And is there a name for the rectangular (like a blade) pins?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. conrad is not one of the large distributors, it's very small and local; mouser, digikey, farnell, rs components are the large ones, mostly. You're on the right track, again, I can't do this any better than you can! You might have to go through a hundred pictures in the end, just like anyone else would.

Comment: I finally found it at RS components, I like their filters. It’s a Hirosen DP50. Thanks for your help pointing me to the right direction.